# Norm of an operator in $l^2$ and $L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Imagine you are given the following operator in a $l^2$ space, where:
$$
\mathbf x = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \dots)
$$
with norm:
$$
\lvert \lvert \mathbf x \rvert \rvert^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\alpha_n|^2
$$
and:
$$
f(x) = T \mathbf x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n e_n(x)
$$
Where $e_n(x)$ is a function (similar to a Fourier basis).
Now this operator transforms a vector from $l^2$ to an $L^2[a, b]$ with a 2-norm. Now if I want to bound the norm of the operator:
$$
\lvert \lvert  T \rvert \rvert \leq \text{sup} \frac{\lvert \lvert  T \mathbf x \rvert \rvert}{\lvert \lvert \mathbf x \rvert \rvert}
$$
But I have a doubt. When I want to find the norm the operator, I use the 2-norm:
$$
\lvert \lvert T \mathbf x \rvert \rvert = \int_a^b |f(x)|^2 \; dx
$$
The thing is: Is $||\mathbf x||$ modified by the change of spaces $(l^2 \to L^2[a, b])$ or it remains the same. Same as for the norm of the operator, does it change, because how would you use the norm of $l^2$ onto a $L^2$ function?

Answer (score 1):

Be very careful when using operators that go between different spaces. If we wish to measure how quantities vary in these spaces, we need to consider the norms on each space separately.

To compute the operator norm, you use the norms on the domain and co-domain. Using more precise notation, we would have

$$\|T\|_{\ell^2\to L^2[a,b]} = \sup_{x\neq0\in\ell^2}\frac{\|Tx\|_{L^2[a,b]}}{\|x\|_{\ell^2}}.$$